# Moving point that can never get to a specified point

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

How can I prove that a moving point from point A(1,1) with the initial conditions $v0=(1,3)$ due to the $F_{x}=y ,F_{y}=x$ force can never get to point C(2,-3)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is the only force acting on the body you can just explicitly solve the equations of motion by integration.

We know $\vec{F} = m \vec{a}$ and $\vec{a} = \frac{d^2\vec{x}}{dt^2} \equiv \vec{x}''$ now plug in $F$ and $m$ the result is a set of differential equations of the form
$x'' = my, y'' = mx$. Differentiating the second equation twice we get $y^{(4)} = mx'' \implies y^{(4)}/m = x'' = my \implies y^{(4)} = m^2y$ which is seperable and can be solved by integration. Then plug in your $4$ initial conditions to get the exact path of your point. Now you can check that this never takes the value you assumed.